# Getting Controller does not exist after moving my controller to sub folder in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, resources, controllers

I have created a resource full route which was pointing to a CRUD controller in `App/Http/Controller/SeatController.php` 
my Route in `api.php`

Route::resource('websites', 'SeatController');

I wanted to put all controllers related to `Seat` inside a directory. I created a directory named `Seat` and I moved all of my controllers related to Seat to it. it's path is : `App\Http\Controllers\Seat\SeatController`

before change it's path was : `App\Http\Controllers\SeatController`

After above changes I added Seat directory name to my resource full route like :

```
Route::resource('websites', 'Seat\SeatController');
```

But when I'm reaching this controller I get below error message :

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Seat\SeatController does not exist
```

**UPDATE :**
my `SeatController.php` file is like :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Seat;
use Auth;
use Validator;

class SeatController extends Controller
{
```

When I change it to :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Seat;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Seat;
use Auth;
use Validator;

class SeatController extends Controller
{
```

I Get this error message :

```
SeatController.php line 12:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Seat\Controller' not found
```

any one knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Update your controller's namespace as                                            namespace App\Http\Controllers\Seat\SeatController;

Comment: You should change your `model` call in the `SeatController` .It should work. And also check namespace is ok or not.

Comment: @NazmulHasan When I update their namespace I get this error message : SeatController.php line 13:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Seat\SeatController\Controller' not found

Comment: Line 13 is : class SeatController extends Controller

Comment: Sorry I have mistake. Namespace will be App\Http\Controllers\Seat;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Seat\SeatController does not exist

This means controller can not find out the `SeatController` class. You should check following steps. Hope this will be worked for you.

First you have to check `model` call in your `SeatController` file is ok or not. And then check your namespace in `SeatController` is ok or not. Try with Something like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Seat;

use App\Seat; \\type your Model name instead of Seat
```

Comment: @Chnochol Mahmud thanks for respondig, but should put this namespace in my api.php or my controller ? my model name is Seat which is in App\Seat;

Comment: You should edit your `controller` namespace specifically you should edit `SeatController`. Your route files looks ok. Or add your `SeatController`  heading code in your question so that i can answer it thoroughly.

Comment: I have done what you said but if you look at the above comments I get another error message. SeatController.php line 13:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Seat\SeatController\Controller' not found

Comment: You have missed `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` add this in your controller file.

Comment: It Solved my problem